# Is it important to get a massage? Or is yoga is better?

Tags: bodyweight-exercises, stretching, yoga, relaxation

I have been going to the gym for almost 6 months and have never once had a massage. I do yoga for relaxation and stretching. I don't like getting massages. Is this good for my body and its growth?

Comment: Massage and Yoga are very different in what they achieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While massages are helpful for relaxation, relieving muscle knots, and alleviating tension in specific, hard-to-reach areas, yoga is an excellent alternative; especially if you don't like getting massages.

If you enjoy yoga for relaxation and find that your muscles get adequately stretched in your practice and the body is free from tension, you will not be missing out if you don't get a massage. If you enjoy yoga, just do yoga.

Yin-style yoga is great for surface and deep muscle stretching. You can also use foam rollers, tennis balls or PVC pipe to work out any muscle knots at home.